# Best way to deal with categorical variables in regression problem - python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression

I am not sure what is the most effective way to deal with categorical variables for a regression problem.

My table looks like :

```
Date        Category    Sales

1/1/2018     Shoes       200

1/2/2018     Shoes       300

1/1/2018     home        100
```

The problem I am dealing with is sales forecasting.

What is the best way to deal with the Category column? Get dummies or label encoder?
I used label encoder, followed by the standard scaler but I got very poor fitting.
After that I  scaled all my inputs (`date, category`) with the exception of the `y` v`ariable (Sales).`

Comment: dummies / label encoder is a common way

Comment: One-Hot Encoding is one solution to it.

Comment: You shouldn't use a LabelEncoder. See [LabelEncoder for categorical features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217713/labelencoder-for-categorical-features/61217936#61217936). You should use either a OneHot encoder, or if the cardinality is huge you may look into bayesian encoders. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585507/how-to-encode-a-categorical-feature-with-high-cardinality/61587769#61587769)

Answer (score 1):

Label encoder isn't recommended.

Target encoding if the cardinality of data is high else you can try both one-hot encoding and target encoding.

Sample Notebook using target encoding for time series forecasting  : https://www.kaggle.com/avvinci/time-series-forecasting-beginners  [cell 21]

More on target encoding : https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/target-encoding/

Good tutorial on categorical variables here: https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science#syllabus [Section: Feature Preprocessing and Generation with Respect to Models , 3rd Video]