# TensorFlow:Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am practicing on this kaggle dataset regarding car price prediction (https://www.kaggle.com/hellbuoy/car-price-prediction). I dont know why am I receiving this error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import layers,models

cars_data=pd.read_csv('/content/CarPrice_Assignment.csv')
cars_data.head()

cars_data.info()

cars_data.describe()

train_data=cars_data.iloc[:103]
train_data=train_data.drop('price',axis=1)
train_data=np.asarray(train_data.values)

train_targets=cars_data.price.iloc[:103]
train_targets=np.asarray(train_targets)

test_data=cars_data.iloc[103:165]
test_data=test_data.drop('price',axis=1)
test_data=np.asarray(test_data.values)

test_targets=cars_data.price.iloc[103:165]
test_targets=np.asarray(test_targets)

val_data=cars_data.iloc[165:]
val_data=val_data.drop('price',axis=1)
val_data=np.asarray(val_data.values)

val_targets=cars_data.price.iloc[165:]
val_targets=np.asarray(val_targets)


model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='relu',input_shape=(25,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(6,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(train_data,train_targets,epochs=20,batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Have you seen that .csv data? I think there is some columns maybe a string, and that strings raises error.

Comment: @yakhyo thanks for your reply. I have seen it. There are some categorical datatypes. So what should I do? Categorize it using to_Categorial()?

Comment: I think you should change them to categorical

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to address in your code.

1. **Categorical Variables**
   By printing the value of train_data, I can see there are still some categorical variables in form of string. Tensorflow cannot process that kind of data directly, so you need to deal with categorical variables. See answer from [Best way to deal with categorical variables in regression problem - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791546/best-way-to-deal-with-categorical-variables-in-regression-problem-python) as your starting point.
2. **target shape**
   Your train_targets shape is (107,) means that this is a 1D array. The correct shape for tensorflow input(for simple regression problem) is (107,1). Modify your code like this to reshape the value :
   `train_targets=np.asarray(train_targets).reshape(-1,1)`