# How to encode high cardinality feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with more 1500+ category in single feature. how to encode these feature ? I tried with target encoding but there is category mismatch in training and test dataset. For example in training dataset there is A,B,C category of feature X while in test dataset there is A,B,D,F category of feature X ?

How to deal with category mismatch and encode categorical variable with high cardinality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode a categorical feature with high cardinality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585507/how-to-encode-a-categorical-feature-with-high-cardinality)

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.